# SSD Setup OS/Programs/Documents

Tags: hard-drive, performance, ssd

I am trying to configure a new computer using SSD's. Am leaning toward the following configuration:

1) SSD of about 120GB solely for OS
2) SSD of about 120GB solely for programs I would use (MS Office, Accounting Software, VS, Other web programming tools and/or graphics programs)
3) SSD of about 250GB for games.
4) HD for documents, photos (probably 2TB).

I've read that SSD's, while great, may require that you allocate some of the space so they don't degrade as quickly (i.e., a full SSD will perform slower if constantly written to).

I was originally going to get one 500GB SSD and one HD, but now am thinking the above configuration may work better. Of course, I could just go with two SSD's and get a bigger second one for programs/games.

In the end, it seems that SSD's are better suited for OS/programs, as the constant re-writes for files like Word/Excel/PDF documents will quickly degrade the SSD.

Thoughts?

My new setup will be AMD FX 9590 with 32GB running Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have only one 128GB SSD. I sometimes install multiple OSes and basic programs that I use (even PhotoShop, Premiere Pro, etc.) and I did not experience slowness because I store more data on the drive. I would only recommend to turn off virtual memory/swap and hibernation files on the SSDs.